# How do I clear Bootstrap 4 errors after I submit my React form?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, form-submit

I'm using React 16.13.0 with Bootstrap 4.  I have the following component created, that I use in my React form ...

```
const Input = (props) => {
    return (  
  <div className="form-group">
      <FormLabel>{props.title}</FormLabel>
      <FormControl
            isInvalid={props.errors && Boolean(props.errors[props.name])}
            type={props.type}
            id={props.name}
            name={props.name}
            value={props.value}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            onChange={props.handleChange}
          />

      {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
          <FormControl.Feedback type="invalid">
                 {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (
                     <div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
                 ))} 
          </FormControl.Feedback>
      )}
  </div>
    )
}

export default Input;
```

Below is the handle form submit function as well as some of the container where I create my form ...

```
  async handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const NC = this.state.newCoop;
    delete NC.address.country;

    try { 
      const response = await fetch(FormContainer.REACT_APP_PROXY + '/coops/',{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.newCoop),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        window.flash('Record has been created successfully!', 'success') 
        return result;
      }
      throw await response.json();
    } catch (errors) {
      console.log('_error_: ', errors);
      this.setState({ errors });
    }  
  }

...

  render() {
    if (this.state.coopTypes && !this.state.coopTypes.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <FormGroup
                controlId="formBasicText">      

                <Input inputType={'text'}
                   title= {'Name'} 
                   name= {'name'}
                   value={this.state.newCoop.name} 
                   placeholder = {'Enter cooperative name'}
                   handleChange = {this.handleInput}
                   errors = {this.state.errors} 
                   /> {/* Name of the cooperative */}
```

The issue is, after I submit my form, if there were errors from the previous run, they are still displayed on the screen.

[image]

Is there a standard way to clear out Bootstrap error displays after a successful form submission?

Comment: How to set validation error ?  I think clear error message or set error state  like ''  when input onchange.  not after form submission.

Comment: Are you using `react-bootstrap` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `this.state.errors` to provide the error information prop to your `<Input>` component, you simply need to update your `handleInput(...)` function to clear `this.state.errors` when your input value changes. The idea is something like this:

```
handleInput = (event) => {
  const errors = Object.assign({}, this.state.errors);
  const target = event.target;

  // remove the error value for a specific input only
  delete errors[target.name];
  this.setState({ errors });

  // Do whatever else needs to be done here for your input
}
```

Here's a working sample of how this works: https://jsfiddle.net/4gqr0cfa/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add or remove form validation based on whether form is valid or not. To do this, add `validated` prop on the `Form` which is initially set to false.

#### How can i make it work?

Follow below mentioned steps:

1. create a boolean state variable in the component containing the `Form` and its initial value should be false.

   ```
   const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);
   ```
2. add a prop named `validated` on the form and set its value equal to the boolean state variable created in step 1.

   ```
   <Form validated={validated}>
      ...
   </Form>
   ```
3. When form is submitted, check if form is valid, if it is, set state variable, `validated`, to `true`.

Here's a working demo

```js
function App() {
  const [ validated, setValidated ] = React.useState(false);
  const [ form, setForm ] = React.useState({
    fields: {
      name: { type: 'text', value: '', title: 'Name' },
      email: { type: 'email', value: '', title: 'Email' },
      password: { type: 'password', value: '', title: 'Password' }
    },
    errors: {}
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const errors = {};
    let invalid = false;

    Object.entries(form.fields).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (!errors[k]) errors[k] = [];
      
      if (!v.value) {
        errors[k].push(`${k} is required`);
        invalid = true;
      }

      if (k === 'email' && !v.value.includes('@')) {
        errors[k].push('enter a valid email address');
        invalid = true;
      }

      if (k === 'password' && v.value.length < 8) {
        errors[k].push('password should be atleast 8 characters long');
        invalid = true;
      }
    });

    setForm({ ...form, errors });

    if (invalid) {
      setValidated(false);
    } else {
      setValidated(true); 
    }
  };

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const updatedField = { ...form.fields[target.name], value: target.value };
    
    const fields = { 
      ...form.fields,
      [target.name]: updatedField
    };

    setForm({ ...form, fields });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: '300px', margin: '10px auto'}}>
      <ReactBootstrap.Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {
          Object.entries(form.fields).map(([k, v]) => {
            return (
              <Input
                key={k}
                title={v.title}
                type={v.type}
                name={k}
                value={v.value}
                placeholder={v.title}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                errors={form.errors}
              />
            );
          })
        }
        <ReactBootstrap.Button type="submit">Submit form</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </ReactBootstrap.Form>
    </div>
  );
}



const Input = (props) => {
    return (  
      <ReactBootstrap.Form.Group>
        <ReactBootstrap.FormLabel>{props.title}</ReactBootstrap.FormLabel>
        <ReactBootstrap.FormControl
          isInvalid={
            Array.isArray(props.errors[props.name])
             ? props.errors[props.name].length > 0
                 ? true : false
             : false
          }
          type={props.type}
          id={props.name}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
        />

        {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
            <ReactBootstrap.FormControl.Feedback type="invalid">
                  {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (
                      <div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
                  ))} 
            </ReactBootstrap.FormControl.Feedback>
        )}
      </ReactBootstrap.Form.Group>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/1.1.0-rc.0/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You can also view the same demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fj1nz7?file=Input.js)

You can improve the above demo by indicating to the user that the input field is valid or invalid by adding green or red border repectively by using `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes.

```js
function App() {
  const [ validated, setValidated ] = React.useState(false);
  const [ form, setForm ] = React.useState({
    fields: {
      name: { type: 'text', value: '', title: 'Name' },
      email: { type: 'email', value: '', title: 'Email' },
      password: { type: 'password', value: '', title: 'Password' }
    },
    errors: {}
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const errors = {};
    let invalid = false;

    Object.entries(form.fields).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      if (!errors[k]) errors[k] = [];
      
      if (!v.value) {
        errors[k].push(`${k} is required`);
        invalid = true;
      }

      if (k === 'email' && !v.value.includes('@')) {
        errors[k].push('enter a valid email address');
        invalid = true;
      }

      if (k === 'password' && v.value.length < 8) {
        errors[k].push('password should be atleast 8 characters long');
        invalid = true;
      }
    });

    setForm({ ...form, errors });

    if (invalid) {
      setValidated(false);
    } else {
      setValidated(true); 
    }
  };

  const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
    const updatedField = { ...form.fields[target.name], value: target.value };
    
    const fields = { 
      ...form.fields,
      [target.name]: updatedField
    };

    setForm({ ...form, fields });
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: '300px', margin: '10px auto'}}>
      <ReactBootstrap.Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {
          Object.entries(form.fields).map(([k, v]) => {
            return (
              <Input
                key={k}
                title={v.title}
                type={v.type}
                name={k}
                value={v.value}
                placeholder={v.title}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                errors={form.errors}
              />
            );
          })
        }
        <ReactBootstrap.Button type="submit">Submit form</ReactBootstrap.Button>
      </ReactBootstrap.Form>
    </div>
  );
}



const Input = (props) => {
    return (  
      <ReactBootstrap.Form.Group>
        <ReactBootstrap.FormLabel>{props.title}</ReactBootstrap.FormLabel>
        <ReactBootstrap.FormControl
          isInvalid={
            Array.isArray(props.errors[props.name])
             ? props.errors[props.name].length > 0
                 ? true : false
             : false
          }
          type={props.type}
          id={props.name}
          name={props.name}
          value={props.value}
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onChange={props.handleChange}
          className={
             Array.isArray(props.errors[props.name])
             ? props.errors[props.name].length > 0 ? 'is-invalid': 'is-valid'
             : ''
          }
        />

        {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
            <ReactBootstrap.FormControl.Feedback type="invalid">
                  {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (
                      <div key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
                  ))} 
            </ReactBootstrap.FormControl.Feedback>
        )}
      </ReactBootstrap.Form.Group>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/1.1.0-rc.0/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

View this demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vwrcey?file=index.js)

You can read about the form validation in bootstrap at the official docs of [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation) and [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#validation)